# Create cell dynamic width UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a problem with UICollectionViewCell.

How can I make the cell width the same on all screens?

on iPhone 13pro max, everything looks great

[image]

on iPhone se, cells in one line

[image]

Here I configure collectionView

```
    private func makeCollectionView() -> UICollectionView {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 190, height: 174)
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 8, bottom: 16, right: 8)
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.register(MenuCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MenuCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifer)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return collectionView
}
```

How can I implement one size for all screens?

Comment: do you truly mean "same size" as in the exact same dimensions OR do you mean you would like the brown views to take up the same proportion (2 width wise) like they do on the first phone?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem!
I did not calculate the cell size correctly.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let flowayout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let space: CGFloat = (flowayout?.minimumInteritemSpacing ?? 0.0) + (flowayout?.sectionInset.left ?? 0.0) + (flowayout?.sectionInset.right ?? 0.0)
    let size: CGFloat = (collectionView.frame.size.width - space) / 2.0
    return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
}
```